# Does there exist a real $\alpha$ such that series $\{n^\alpha x_n\}$ converges to a non-zero number?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $x_{n+1}=x_n(1-x_n^2)$, $x_1 \in (0,1)$, does there exist a real $\alpha$ such that series $\{n^\alpha x_n\}$ converges to non-zero number?

I have written a program to check if the series converges. Plugging in $\alpha=1/2$ it seems that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{(\sqrt{n}~x_n)}$ always converges to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, but I couldn't find an elegant way to prove that.

So far, I have proved that $\lim{\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}}=1$ and $x_{n+1}<x_n$, but I didn't find that very useful.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit seems correct to me: Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be defined as $f(t)=t(1-t^2)$. The recursion is then $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ and clearly $x_n \in (0,1)$ $(n \in \mathbb{N})$. Since $f(x) < x$ $(x \in (0,1))$ and $f(0)=0$ the sequence $(x_n)$ is decreasing with limit $0$. Next
$$
\lim_{t\to 0+} \frac{t^2-f(t)^2}{t^2f(t)^2} =2.
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{1}{x_{n+1}^2} - \frac{1}{x_{n}^2} = \frac{x_n^2-f(x_n)^2}{x_n^2f(x_n)^2}
\to 2 \quad (n \to \infty).
$$
Cesaro's Limit Theorem yields
$$
\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_{n+1}^2} - \frac{1}{x_{1}^2}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{x_{k+1}^2} - \frac{1}{x_{k}^2}\right) \to 2 \quad (n \to \infty).
$$
Thus (as $1/(n x_1^2) \to 0$)
$$
\frac{1}{nx_{n+1}^2} \to 2 \quad (n \to \infty),
$$
that is
$$
\sqrt{n}x_{n+1} \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \quad (n \to \infty).
$$
Finally
$$
\sqrt{n+1}x_{n+1} = \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{n}x_{n+1} \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \quad (n \to \infty).
$$